# Changing width value doesn't change the width?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 "panes" or columns side by side. I want the middle one `.mid-pane` to take up most of the space. But changing any of the width values doesn't seem to do anything. I say `width: 10px;` and nothing happens. What's going on?
https://jsfiddle.net/agtfwmhq/1/

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.maindiv {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container>div {
  flex: 1;
  /*grow*/
}

.left-pane {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #5897fb;
}

.mid-pane {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.right-pane {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ffefef;
}
```

```html
<div class="maindiv container">
  <div class="left-pane">
  </div>

  <div class="mid-pane">
  </div>

  <div class="right-pane">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove   `flex: 1;
  /*grow*/`

Comment: Remove `flex: 1` from your `.container > div`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change it below CSS to work it. Giving Flexgrow property will do the magic

```
.

/** comment this
  * container > div {
  * flex: 1; /*grow*/
  * } */

.left-pane {
    flex: 1;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #5897fb;
}
.mid-pane {
    flex: 2;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
}
.right-pane {
    flex: 1;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ffefef;
}
```